# Refresh All on a PowerQuery from a Web Query not pulling updated data - Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

Sorry for the long title. I am trying to "refresh all" on an Excel PowerQuery. The query should go to the website http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/coal/coal-api-4-fob-richards-bay-argus-mccloskey.html and pull the table there. When I set this up in a new spreadsheet it works fine. However the following day(s), when I refresh all it often will not go to the website and grab the new data. I can go to the website and see it has updated but the PowerQuery setup will not grab it. Can someone advise what is causing the issue of it not retrieving the new info when hitting refresh all?

Answer (score 0):

Use **IsRetry** flag in Web.Contents function to force PQ ignore cache

```
response = Web.Contents(your_url, [IsRetry=true])
```

Comment: I want to verify again tomorrow that it works but this seems to have worked

Comment: I have run this the past two days and it does not appear to have solved the issue. The refresh works as before after a couple hours in the morning. I don't know if this is some magical website setting or something in excel.